# Receive multiple messages on same socket

Tags: java, sockets, message

I've been studying Java for 4 months and decided to make a simple Texas Holdem game with javaFX. The client connects to the Server and the server creates a new thread for each client (max 10 clients).

My problem is to handle multiple messages at the same time. If you look at my code below you will understand: (This is the client)

```
while (true){
            messageIn = in.readUTF();

            if (messageIn.equals("seat")){
                String name = in.readUTF();
                String seat = in.readUTF();
                gameScreenController.addPlayerToSeat(name, seat);
            }
            else if (messageIn.equals("hand")){
                String seat = in.readUTF();
                int handCard1 = in.readInt();
                int handCard2 = in.readInt();
                gameScreenController.handCardToSeat(handCard1, handCard2, seat);
            }
            else if (messageIn.equals("flopp")){
                int floppCard1 = in.readInt();
                int floppCard2 = in.readInt();
                int floppCard3 = in.readInt();
                gameScreenController.flopp(floppCard1, floppCard2, floppCard3);
            }
            else if (messageIn.equals("turn")){
                int turnCard = in.readInt();
                gameScreenController.turn(turnCard);
            }
            else if (messageIn.equals("river")){
                int riverCard = in.readInt();
                gameScreenController.turn(riverCard);
            }   
        }
```

1. the client connects
2. It will listen for messages

As you can see, it is possible for the messages to collide if you recieve a playername and playerseat at the same moment as you receive the flopp cards.

My question is how I can avoid this? What do I need or what could I search for to solve this.
I will be grateful for all hints or answers I could get! :)

Comment: On one socket connection, you'll receive data sent from one client, and messages (as those above) will arrive one after the other. (You *connect* on one listen socket, but the *accept* creates an individual data socket.)

Comment: laune: the problem is that when a client connects, a new thread is started on the server side, and the first thing that happends is that the thread on the server will first listen for your name to be sent. And after that the playerSeat. ANd as soon as the server has received the playerSeat, the thread will send the seat to all the other clentThreads. And this could happen while a gameround is active. so the messages could collide.

Comment: AFAIK, a new player can only enter the game between deals. New player threads must be queued and delayed until joining is possible.

Comment: Laune: That's a smart solution but what if there are 4 persons who's waiting and they sit down at the same time,then messages will collide too. Thanks for answer!

Comment: I don't think so. Threads in the server should listen to some Table event and notify their player client of the goings-on. So, each thread knows about the +4 and notifies its client. Look into state machines, the basic design tool for protocols.

Comment: Laune I will go with your solution, really thank you man! Answer what you wrote in the comment and I mark it as Answer. 
Thanks!!

Comment: I think I collected everything. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server, a player is represented as a thread, reading and writing the data socket obtained by the accept. The "Table" (or client control sw) is responsible for directing game events to individual or all players, passing messages to be sent to the pertaining thread(s).

Some events should be held back until the current deal (or round) reaches its end, e.g., a new player sitting down at the table. This can be implemented by setting up a queue to each player/thread, to be read whenever the game reaches the inter-round state.

During a deal, a state machine can control what is acceptable from a player - although the players should be programmed according to the protocol: e.g., when asked what to do, must respond with whatever action the game permits.